# Как упорядочить таблицу по дням недели?

Tags: access, delphi-7, sql

Здраствуйте.

Как можно при упорядочить таблицу по дням недели (не `asc/desc`) в порядке понедельник-воскресенье?

Таблица - расписание.

Поле - [День недели].

Значения в полях соответствуют понедельник - воскресенье, берутся из PickList DBGridEh1.

Comment: Объединять с вспомогательной таблицей, задающей для дней порядок.

Comment: создай скрытное поле числовое, где будет указан код недели. Сортируй по нему, тогда и дни недели будут представленны в порядке возрастания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
..
ORDER BY DatePart('w', [День недели], 2);
```

2 тут означает константу vbMonday - начинать отсчет с понедельника

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку.

Хм.. но при написании "adoQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM расписание ORDER BY DatePart('w', [День недели], 2');" выдвет "Слишком мало параметров. Требуется 1.", может я что не так написал?

Comment: > Спасибо за подсказку.

> Хм.. но при написании "adoQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM расписание ORDER BY > DatePart('w', [День недели], 2');" выдвет "Слишком мало параметров. 
> Требуется 1.", может я что не так написал?

Я у Вас в **DatePart('w', [День недели], 2')** после 2-ки вижу ковычку, а вот закрывющейся скобки нет. И скорее всего ковычки, которыми обрамлена **w**, надо экранировать